# Mouse dead zone in bottom left of Windows 10 display

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse

I have a Mouse dead zone in the bottom left-hand corner of my Windows 10 primary display, right above the start button. I can move the mouse cursor there, but clicks get ignored.

Using Winspector and Spy++, I discovered the dead zone is caused by an invisible, transparent window with class **StartMenuSizingFrame** and ex-style bit `WS_EX_TOPMOST`.

I'm running Windows version 10.0.15063 Build 15063.

Known bug? Anyone else encounter this? How to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Window is owned by `explorer.exe`.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> to open Task Manager. Find the process called "Windows Explorer", right-click it, and pick "Restart" from the popup context menu. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on another user's computer, but restarting the computer and restarting "Windows Explorer" did not work.

I fixed this by going to "Display Settings" > Display Resolution > a smaller resolution.

It worked. I went back to the original resolution and it continued to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solutions above to see if they work. Restarting `explorer.exe` did not work for me. Changing the resolution does work.

The most simple solutions, at least with dual monitors, is you can hit the power button on the monitor so it power cycles. The power cycle may also work with single monitor setups. I've yet to actually figure out what causes the problem.